Usage of plural form of "threat"
Is it just me, or does the plural form of "threat" in this sentence not sound natural?

People working in the army or the police force must not become threats to public safety.


it's just you, and probably a few other people ... a threat could also be used

One person, one threat; two people, two threats.

I thought the first sentence of the comment on the ELU version of this question explained adequately: "People" is typically a plural noun. Instead of reposting the same words, it might be helpful to explain more about why this didn't explain it for you.

Singular "threat" would be a perfectly valid option, but would hold a slightly different meaning.
Recognize that one singular thing can be made up of multiple things. A book, singular, is made up of many pages, plural. I could say "These 11 players are," plural, "a football team," singular. So yes, these plural "people" could be seen as "a threat," singular.
But recognize as well that an individual person can be an individual threat. If 10 bad soldiers, in 10 different divisions, threaten civilians, then each of them is "a threat to public safety," and we can say that we have 10 "threats," plural. If we saw this as a broader problem to be solved and wanted to speak about the phenomenon in general, we would say that all such soldiers were "a threat."
I'm not sure it would have mattered much to the author's point, since they're already speaking in broad, generic terms, but their point seems to be not so much about a broad threat to society at large, as about the potential of each individual to threaten the individual people surrounding them.
